# How calculate a new data frame aggregating values from another data frame?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which structure looks like this

[image]

I would like to create reshuffle the way data is presented by creating a new data frame where I summarise the data above and it looks like this:

[image]

Therefore, for each European country, I will be creating 4 variables which are  a sum of the capital expenditure variable based on different conditions. Lets take the first one as an example:

[image]

This is the sum of total capital expenditure that is directed to Austria (so Destination country= 'Austria') from EU countries (Source country continent=EU).

Can someone indicate the code to create a new df with this structure and create the variable explained above?

Thanks a lot!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html - Something like `pivot_longer(mydf, c(source_country, destination_country), names_to = "source_destination", values_to = "country")`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.